# Connecting Samsung S9 to MacBook's USB Type-C behaves like charging - not charging - charging - etc

Tags: adb, usb, charging, usb-debugging, macos

I am trying to use my Samsung S9 to test a mobile app. I activated the "Developer options" and these are my "USB settings" (opened when I tap on the "Android System" notification):

[image]

And when I "Tap for more settings" I see:

[image]

Now every 10 seconds my phone will behave as if I would just plug it the USB cable back in again making the charging noise and showing the battery percentage:

[image]

1. This does not sound healthy for the battery of my phone if these are indeed battery cycles.
2. How can I stop charging or stop in the state charging? (If I select that the USB controlled by options "Connected device", I don't see anymore the phone with `adb` and my MAcBook starts charging from my phone.)

Comment: Disable charging while connected via USB requires a special data-only USB cable or a rooted Android device so that charging can be disabled by software. However the behavior you describe sounds buggy. May be the USB cable is defect or there is a driver issue on your Mac causing the device to permanently reconnect.

Comment: I have the same behaviour with all 3 cables I have. When connected to the charger, no such behaviour happens. I only see it when I connect the phone to my MacBook Pro USB-C port (any of the 4 ports)

Comment: Could it be the app under test that's causing this? If this behavior persists in safe mode then it is surely app related

Comment: See this for  safe mode https://www.thecustomdroid.com/enter-samsung-galaxy-s9-safe-mode/